How do i prevent changes directly to a specific branch in ADF (GitHub)?
I've established a git integration between my DEV data factory and my GitHub repo. I'm using three different branches:

DEV (Collaboration branch)
adf_publish (stores arm templates generated by the ADF)
BLD (stores arm templates ready for deployment to test/prod Factory)

When i'm in my DEV Factory, i have the option to work inside the DEV Branch as well as the BLD Branch. Since we're strictly using Feature-Branches, neither of them should be accessible from the ADF. Is there a way i can protect these two branches from being accessible from inside the ADF?
Online, i'm only finding threads about Azure DevOps but im using GitHub.
I tried setting a protection rule for DEV and BLD to require pull requests with 1 reviewer but it seemed to change nothing. I could still create a pipeline in ADF directly in the DEV Branch.
